# Why is Salesforce asking more permissions than the ones listed in the connected app?

Tags: oauth2

We created a new Connected App in Salesforce with appropriate scopes to allow users of our service to oAuth with Salesforce. However, today I noticed that when logging in the user is asked by Salesforce for more scopes than the ones listed in the app. For example, is also adding a scope for things like "Manage Salesforce CDP ingestion API data". How could this happen? It seems like it started happening today.

I am 100% sure that I am using the same connected app to login. In other words, I am sure I am looking at the correct connected app configuration.

Scopes like "Manage Salesforce CDP ingestion API data" are legitimate scopes but I was not able to find any connected app in our organization that included that scope.

Comment: I suggest you double-check the Connected App in use (you can see this through Set UI and the Connected App usage for your user) and double check that app's setup on the org it was created. You could also double check if it was a one-off or is happening every time, and consider seeing if the Connected App host org or target org was updated with a new Salesforce patch (via status.salesforce.com) over the timescales you have in mind for this unexpected change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Salesforce support I realized this is because the Connected App included the "Full Access" scope that encompasses all other scopes, as mentioned in the official Salesforce documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/oauth_scope_parameter_values.htm). I think Salesforce might have recently changed the way they display scopes to list all scopes instead of simply listing the "Full Access" item, I would love to get a confirmation from somebody else but until then that is my best guess.